# Look for available "spots" in a set

Tags: python, random, sequence

I'm looking for a way to programmatically look for an available (not used) spot in a list, usually a set of criteria.  I could give you the example of a phone book: I'll generate phone numbers with specific rules (like, in this case, 7 digits, that's quite simple).  The "generator" would choose an available number at random.  This number won't be in the generator for the next try.

```
generator = PhoneNumberGenerator()
generator.generate()
"559-608-XXXX"
# This number won't be available next time the generator.generate is called
```

One possibility would be to store "used" phone numbers in a sorted list and look for the first available possibility.  But that wouldn't be very random.  The first generated number would be 000-0000, the second 000-0001 and so on.  Another possibility would be to create the full list of all available phone numbers and remove these that are used already, but that would be a huge list.  Assuming the generator is often used, performances would probably suffer.

Of course, I'm using the example of a phone number generator here, but that could be a different generator, for license plates or validation codes or whatever else, just defined by a set of rules.  I'm trying to do that in Python, so examples in this language are welcome, but if you have articles to the theory in a different language, don't hesitate either, I'll just edit the question to include the answer if I can.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I find this a bit verbose, show a small code snippet example that illustrates your issue

Comment: @Chris_Rands I did, but it might not be very helpful without the text, actually.

Comment: Do you know how often you will be using the generator before hand?

Comment: Why not store 'used' numbers in a `set` and then after you randomly generate the next one, just check if it's in the `set`; if it is in the set already, just generate another number

Comment: because with a lot of entries (like one million on ten possible million of entries), that would have the algorithm generate a lot of numbers and always hitting one that is already used... trying again... hitting another used one... trying again... that would be hard to predict.  The more numbers the more time it would run.  That's probably unavoidable but I'd like something a bit more performance-friendly.

Comment: sorry, I didn't see your question.  The generator will be used only from time to time, not regularly.  It's not a highly-demanding task in terms of performance.  Just wondering how to speed things up a bit.

Comment: If you care about performance and 'a lot of entries'. You could solve the problem vice-versa and create all possible combinations and save them somewhere (database, text file, ...) and pop the first 'number' out. Elsewise you can generate those numbers based on a timestamp.

Comment: Sounds like a Pseudo Random Number generator, just with an algorithm that guarantees no repetitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take two prime numbers, `p` and `q`, and generate the numbers `p * i % q` for `0 <= i < q`. The resulting numbers cover all the numbers from `0` to `q` (exclusive) in seemingly pseudo-random* order with no duplicates or missed numbers.

```
>>> p, q = 7, 11
>>> [p*i % q for i in range(q)]
[0, 7, 3, 10, 6, 2, 9, 5, 1, 8, 4]
>>> sorted(_)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

>>> p, q = 101, 131
>>> [p*i % q for i in range(q)]
[0, 101, 71, ..., 60, 30]
>>> Counter(_).most_common(5)
[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1)]
```

*Proof (not very rigorous):* Assume that there is a duplicate number in the list, i.e. there are `i` and `k` such that `p*i % q == p*k % q`. That would mean that the difference, `p*(k-i)`, would have to be a multiple of `q` (since they are equal modulo `q`), and also a multiple of `p`. But as `p` and `q` are primes, their smallest common multiple is `p*q`, which is never reached with `i < q`. Thus, all the numbers in the list must be unique, and as the list has `q` elements, it has to contain all the numbers from `0` to `q` (exclusive).

Obviously, for phone numbers and the like the prime numbers would be much larger, but (assuming no overflows and the like) the same should work with no significant computational or memory overhead. And if you want to generate numbers within a specific interval, say from `100000` to `999999`, you can pick the prime numbers so that `q` is slightly larger than the amount of numbers, add the minimum as offset to each number, and drop all numbers that are larger than the upper bound. Also, pad numbers with leading zeros.

---

*) Of course, this is not random, not even pseudo-random, just by the criteria that no number can appear twice, and its probably rather easy to figure out the next number to come. But to a "casual" observer they should appear random enough, not being able to determine which of two numbers was generated first, or how many numbers were generated before some given number.

Comment: Thanks.  If I followed correctly this allow to generate the list of numbers (randomly-generated) but this, of course, would raise repetitions if used again.

Comment: @vincent-lg Yes, but you don't have to generate the entire list at once. Just keep track of the current value of `i` and you can generate the numbers as needed. Not sure what you mean by "if used again". Of course, if you use the list again, you get repetitions. You can generate a different list by using different `p` and `q`, and if you have sufficiently large `p` and `q` (say in the millions) you should get a large enough list for all the telephone numbers you need.

Comment: Addendum: If you need/want a bit more pseudo-randomness, you could also cache the next, say, 100 numbers from the generator, randomly pick one from those, and generate a new one for the cache.